# python - import only when required?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my case the Python program has some kind of mods and some mods require special imports. If a mode is not activated at startup, these mode-specific imports should not be checked.

The goal is to start the Python program without the imports, when these are not required for the mode.

Even if I move the import to a separate (mode specific) class, which is not called, an import error message comes up.

Can this be implemented at all?

update:

This seems to work, thanks! @ amir zareian

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':        
        if mode:
          import testimport
```

The other option looks a bit more elegant to me, but the import is not recognized, I tried:

```
class ImportRequired:

    def __init__(self):
        import testimport

    def function(self):
        testimport.testcall()
```

Comment: Putting the import inside a class instance method such as `__init__()` works.  It would probably help to show us what you tried.

Comment: Are the modules particular expensive to load, or are you trying to avoid errors if unneeded modules aren't even installed?

Comment: Yes, If a mode is not used, these imports are not required.

Comment: If someone posted an answer that answered your question - please mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: If your `import` is inside a function, it will only be available inside the function and not in the rest of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to put that input in if condition ? or in switch case ?
for example :

```
if (mode1):
    import first
```

and go on